# react/redux Cannot read property 'setCurrent' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

So im preparing redux for my project and got stuck.
All things seems correctly since, redux devtools shows state.

The problem occurs when I try to invoke function in my component via this.props.function_name

I doing that call in .then(), because I am calling it when axios returns token, i know that scope of this changes in then, but I'm using arrow function with then so the problem seems not to be there.

Also tried to call this.props.setcurrent from another function, but got 
 _this2 is undefined
My code:

Signup.js

```
import {setCurrent} from '../actions/authActions'

class SignUp extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  responseGoogle(response) {
    console.log('google', response);
    const access_token = response.Zi.access_token;
    axios
      .post('http://localhost:3001/users/oauth/google', {
        access_token
      })
      .then((response) =>{
        console.log('google', response);
        const decoded = jwt_decode(response.data.token);
        this.props.setCurrent(decoded);
        console.log(decoded);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
  render() {
    return (
          <GoogleLogin
            clientId="890644813294-bvuq6cf7lsilohneqvov28oi60sfdmig.apps.googleusercontent.com"
            buttonText="Login"
            onSuccess={this.responseGoogle}
            onFailure={this.responseGoogle}
          />
       )
  }
}

export default connect(null, { setCurrent })(SignUp);
```

authActions.js

```
import { TEST_DISPATCH } from './types';

// Testing
export const setCurrent = (userToken) => {
  return {
    type: TEST_DISPATCH,
    payload: userToken
  };
};
```

authReducer.js

```
import { TEST_DISPATCH } from '../actions/types';
const initialState = {
  isAuthenticated: false,
  user: {}
}
export default function(state = initialState, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case TEST_DISPATCH:
      return {
        ...state,
        user: action.payload
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Auth/index.js

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import authReducer from './authReducer';

export default combineReducers({
  auth: authReducer
});
```

store.js

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from './reducers';

const initialState = {};

const middleware = [thunk];

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  initialState,
  compose(
    applyMiddleware(...middleware),
   // window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
  )
);

export default store;
```

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from '../store';
import LogIn from './LogIn';
import SignUp from './SignUp';


class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <Provider store={ store }>
      <div>
      <h1>SignUp!</h1>
      <SignUp />
    </div>
    </Provider>
    )
  }
}
export default App;
```

Full code: https://github.com/ExadelPraktika/Front-exabook/tree/auth
I'm also using babel with webpack

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> i know that scope of this changes in then, but I'm using arrow function with then so the problem seems not to be there.

It is still a scope issue. The method responseGoogle is scoped. So you need to "autobind" it like this :

`responseGoogle = (response) => { /* Your code */ }`

**or** in the render method of the SignUp component :

```
<GoogleLogin
    onSuccess={response => this.responseGoogle(response)}
    onFailure={response => this.responseGoogle(response)}
/>
```

Comment: Would like to point out that he could also bind in the constructor like so: `this.responseGoogle = this.responseGoogle.bind(this);`.

Answer (score 1):

Your thoughts about `this` referring to the incorrect context are correct.  Looking at this code snippet, I have added some comments that might help clarify.

```
class SignUp extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  responseGoogle(response) {
    // "this" does not refer to the class instance here when invoked by
    // the click handler (it is undefined)

    const access_token = response.Zi.access_token;
    axios
      .post('http://localhost:3001/users/oauth/google', {
        access_token
      })
      .then((response) => {
        // Because this is a lambda function, "this" is the same lexical scope
        // as the outer function - but the outer function "this" is undefined
        // *not* the instance of the class (see above)     

        const decoded = jwt_decode(response.data.token);
        this.props.setCurrent(decoded);
        console.log(decoded);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
          <GoogleLogin
            clientId="890644813294-bvuq6cf7lsilohneqvov28oi60sfdmig.apps.googleusercontent.com"
            buttonText="Login"
            onSuccess={this.responseGoogle}
            onFailure={this.responseGoogle}
          />
       )
  }
}
```

There are two common ways of resolving this:

**Use `bind` in the constructor**

```
class SignUp extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.responseGoogle = this.responseGoogle.bind(this);
      }

      responseGoogle(response) {
        const access_token = response.Zi.access_token;
        axios
          .post('http://localhost:3001/users/oauth/google', {
            access_token
          })
          .then((response) => {
            // Because this is a lambda function, "this" is the same lexical scope
            // as the outer function - but the outer function "this" is undefined
            // *not* the instance of the class (see above)     

            const decoded = jwt_decode(response.data.token);
            this.props.setCurrent(decoded);
            console.log(decoded);
          })
          .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
          });
      }

      render() {
        return (
              <GoogleLogin
                clientId="890644813294-bvuq6cf7lsilohneqvov28oi60sfdmig.apps.googleusercontent.com"
                buttonText="Login"
                onSuccess={this.responseGoogle}
                onFailure={this.responseGoogle}
              />
           )
      }
    }
```

JavaScript's bind method exists on functions, and returns a new function that works identically to the original, except its context (its "this") is set to whatever you passed to `bind`.  So we have created a new method, bound to whatever "this" is in the constructor.  In the constructor, "this" is the class instance, so the same will be true in the click handler.

**Use lambda functions instead of class methods**

```
class SignUp extends Component {
    responseGoogle = (response) => {
        const access_token = response.Zi.access_token;
        axios
          .post('http://localhost:3001/users/oauth/google', {
            access_token
          })
          .then((response) =>{
            console.log('google', response);
            const decoded = jwt_decode(response.data.token);
            this.props.setCurrent(decoded);
            console.log(decoded);
          })
          .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
          });
      }
      render() {
        return (
              <GoogleLogin
                clientId="890644813294-bvuq6cf7lsilohneqvov28oi60sfdmig.apps.googleusercontent.com"
                buttonText="Login"
                onSuccess={this.responseGoogle}
                onFailure={this.responseGoogle}
              />
           )
      }
  }
```

This works for the same reason the lambda function callback to `.then` works, by maintaining the outer "this".  The only downside of this method is that it is not a true part of the JS language, so you will need to transpile for it to work (but you're already using babel/webpack so that's not an issue)

Comment: Great explanation - appreciate it